# Did the changing magnetic field broke the translation invariance of the infinite plane and what was the Electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry

Suppose, for the simplicity, a $B$ field where $B\approx 0$ but $\partial_t B\neq 0$. Essentially one might modulate it by a $\sin \omega t$ with $\omega \rightarrow Large$. The $B$ field was translation invariant.

From the Maxwell–Faraday equation
$$\nabla \times E=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$
one could extract
$$2\pi r E=-\partial _tB \pi r^2\Rightarrow E=-\frac{r}{2}\partial_t B$$.

At the finite scale, this expression worked as expected. However, consider an infinite plane.

1. This seemed to be saying that by shifting a point away from the origin, the electric field increase.(draw a circle centered around the origin)
2. a. But then one could argue that the origin of an infinite plane was arbitrary, the electric field should not be changing by shifting the point around.
3. b. In fact, by the counter and the symmetry argument, the electric field ought to be $0$.(draw two infinite squares intersect at y axis.)
4. "But what if the entire infinite plane were shifted a distance $r$? Shouldn't there be a uniformly changing electric field induced".

Did the changing magnetic field broke the translation invariance of the infinite plane and what was the Electric field?

Comment: How did you "extract" that equation without making some very questionable assumptions about symmetries in this situation to begin with?

Comment: @ACuriousMind It's just following the usual counter integral by expanding a disk to infinity. That's actually might be the issue since the limiting procedure might not be well defined. But on the other hand as long as the symmetric configuration was preserved there ought not to be the issue, which seemed to have lead to an indication or conjecture of symmetry breaking.